# Terraform ignoring VPC peering connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

This is a surprise for me as Terraform is ignoring a resource creation. I'm using modules in terraform and every other resource is getting created except `vpc_peering_connection`. It is in fact ignoring that block. Hence, for debugging I created an output for the ID of peering connection and then I get below error:

```
$ terraform plan 

Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on network/output.tf line 6, in output "peering-id":
   6:   value = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.default.id}"

A managed resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "default" has not been
declared in network.
```

This is a tree snap of my code structure.

```
.
├── module-network.tf
├── network
│   ├── data.tf
│   ├── igw.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   ├── peering-conn
│   ├── rt-public.tf
│   ├── security_group.tf
│   ├── subnet.tf
│   ├── var.tf
│   └── vpc.tf
├── output.tf
├── provider-aws.tf
├── terraform.tfstate
├── terraform.tfstate.backup
├── var-static.tf
└── versions.tf

1 directory, 16 files
```

**Terraform Code:**

```
$ cat module-network.tf 
module "network" {
  source       = "./network"
  AWS_REGION   = var.REGION
  ENVIRONMENT  = var.ENVIRONMENT
  PRODUCT      = var.PRODUCT
  VPC_CIDR     = var.VPC_CIDR
  SUBNET_COUNT = var.SUBNET_COUNT
  VPC_PEER_ID  = var.VPC_PEER_ID
}

$ cat output.tf 
output "vpc-id" {
  value = module.network.vpc-id
}

output "peering-id" {
  value =module.network.peering-id
}

variable "PRODUCT" {
  default = "jjmdb"
}

variable "ENVIRONMENT" {
  default = "prod"
}

variable "REGION" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "VPC_CIDR" {
  default = "10.100.0.0/16"
}

variable "SUBNET_COUNT" {
  default = "2"
}

variable "VPC_PEER_ID" {
  default = "vpc-0724db2d24120ca8c"
}

$ cat data.tf

data "aws_vpc" "peer_vpc" {
  id = "${var.VPC_PEER_ID}"
}

data "aws_subnet_ids" "private_nodes" {
  vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.peer_vpc.id}"
  tags = {
    Tier = "node-private"
  }
}


$ cat igw.tf
#Create internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags = {
    Name        = "${format("%s-igw",var.PRODUCT)}"
    Environment = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
}


$ cat output.tf
output "vpc-id" {
    value = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}

output "peering-id" {
    value = "${aws_vpc_peering_connection.default.id}"
}


$ cat peering-conn

#Create VPC Peering connection
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "default" {
  peer_vpc_id   = "${data.aws_vpc.peer_vpc.id}"
  vpc_id        = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  auto_accept   = true

  tags = {
        Name = "${format("%s-peering",var.PRODUCT)}"
        Environment = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
}


$ cat rt-public.tf
#Create a Public Route table
resource "aws_route_table" "rt-public" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"

    tags = {
    Name        = "${format("%s-rt-public",var.PRODUCT)}"
    Environment = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
}

resource "aws_route" "rt-public-route" {
    route_table_id         = "${aws_route_table.rt-public.id}"
    destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id             = "${aws_internet_gateway.igw.id}"
}

#Associate public Route Table to public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt-sub-public" {
  count          = "${var.SUBNET_COUNT}"
    subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.sub_public.*.id[count.index]}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.rt-public.id}"
}


$ cat security_group.tf


$ cat subnet.tf
resource "aws_subnet" "sub_public" {
  count      = "${var.SUBNET_COUNT}"
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(var.VPC_CIDR, 2, count.index + 2)}"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${format("%s-sub-public-%d",var.PRODUCT,count.index)}"
    Environment = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
}


$ cat var.tf
variable "AWS_REGION" {}

variable "ENVIRONMENT" {}

variable "PRODUCT" {}

variable "VPC_CIDR" {}

variable "SUBNET_COUNT" {}

variable "VPC_PEER_ID" {}


$ cat vpc.tf
# Create VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc"{
    cidr_block           = "${var.VPC_CIDR}"
    instance_tenancy     = "default"
    enable_dns_support   = "true"
    enable_dns_hostnames = "true"
    enable_classiclink   = "false"

    tags = {
        Name = "${format("%s-vpc",var.PRODUCT)}"
        Environment = "${var.ENVIRONMENT}"
    }
}
```

If I remove the output blocks, it gets ignored. Terraform plan as below:

```
**Terraform plan**

$ terraform plan 
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

module.network.data.aws_vpc.peer_vpc: Refreshing state...
module.network.data.aws_subnet_ids.private_nodes: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.network.aws_internet_gateway.igw will be created
  + resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + owner_id = (known after apply)
      + tags     = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Name"        = "jjmdb-igw"
        }
      + vpc_id   = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_route.rt-public-route will be created
  + resource "aws_route" "rt-public-route" {
      + destination_cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
      + destination_prefix_list_id = (known after apply)
      + egress_only_gateway_id     = (known after apply)
      + gateway_id                 = (known after apply)
      + id                         = (known after apply)
      + instance_id                = (known after apply)
      + instance_owner_id          = (known after apply)
      + nat_gateway_id             = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id       = (known after apply)
      + origin                     = (known after apply)
      + route_table_id             = (known after apply)
      + state                      = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_route_table.rt-public will be created
  + resource "aws_route_table" "rt-public" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + owner_id         = (known after apply)
      + propagating_vgws = (known after apply)
      + route            = (known after apply)
      + tags             = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Name"        = "jjmdb-rt-public"
        }
      + vpc_id           = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_route_table_association.rt-sub-public[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt-sub-public" {
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + route_table_id = (known after apply)
      + subnet_id      = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_route_table_association.rt-sub-public[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_route_table_association" "rt-sub-public" {
      + id             = (known after apply)
      + route_table_id = (known after apply)
      + subnet_id      = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_subnet.sub_public[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "sub_public" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.100.128.0/18"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                 = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + tags                            = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Name"        = "jjmdb-sub-public-0"
        }
      + vpc_id                          = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_subnet.sub_public[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "sub_public" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.100.192.0/18"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                 = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = false
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + tags                            = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Name"        = "jjmdb-sub-public-1"
        }
      + vpc_id                          = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.network.aws_vpc.vpc will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
      + arn                              = (known after apply)
      + assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = false
      + cidr_block                       = "10.100.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id        = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                  = (known after apply)
      + enable_classiclink               = false
      + enable_classiclink_dns_support   = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_hostnames             = true
      + enable_dns_support               = true
      + id                               = (known after apply)
      + instance_tenancy                 = "default"
      + ipv6_association_id              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                  = (known after apply)
      + main_route_table_id              = (known after apply)
      + owner_id                         = (known after apply)
      + tags                             = {
          + "Environment" = "prod"
          + "Name"        = "jjmdb-vpc"
        }
    }

Plan: 8 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

Note: I was getting the same issue with Terraform version 0.11.1. So, I upgraded  to 0.12.3. But no luck.

Please advise.

Comment: Your `peering-conn` file is missing the `.tf` file extension so Terraform is ignoring it. Notice how the resource doesn't appear in your plan once you remove the outputs that reference it.

Comment: Voted to close as a simple typo.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have been a complete stupid indeed. It works now, thanks for pointing out the silliness !